# awk not print from the first file when merging two files

Tags: unix, awk

I'm trying to merge two files based on specific columns. I used code as below

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$3; next}$1 in a{print a[$2], $0}' temp2.txt temp3.txt
```

My temp2.txt looks like

```
0 a1 0 G T
0 a2 0 A T
0 a3 0 C T
```

and my temp3.txt looks like

```
a1 G
a2 T
a3 C
```

My output is as below

```
 a1 G
 a2 T
 a3 C
```

while my expected out put is

```
0 a1 G
0 a2 T
0 a3 C
```

Is there any reason why matched result from the first file doesn't print?

Comment: `... $1 in a{print a[$1], $0}`?

Comment: @JamesBrown It works. Thank you.

Comment: @JamesBrown It didn't work when I tried to switch between temp2 and temp3. I tried awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}$2 in a{print a[$1], $0}' temp3.txt temp2.txt   Is there any reasons for that?

Comment: `... $2 in a{print a[$2], $0}`. You test `$2 in a` therefore you must reference the `a` with the same field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this with the `join` command:

```
join -o 1.1 1.2 2.2 -1 2 -2 1 temp2.txt temp3.txt
```

That is: output column 1 and column 2 from file 1 and column 2 from file 2 (`-o 1.1 1.2 2.2`), joining on column 2 from file 1 and column 1 from file two (`-1 2 -2 1`).

The `awk` alternative to print all columns from file one (temp2.txt) can be something like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}$2 in a{print $0, a[$2]}' temp3.txt temp2.txt
```

Output:

```
0 a1 0 G T G
0 a2 0 A T T
0 a3 0 C T C
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm just wondering what should I put in output if I want to print all columns from file 1 while there are like hundreds of columns?

Comment: If temp3.txt is just two columns as in your example, you can use `join -1 2 -2 1 temp2.txt temp3.txt`, otherwise I think you should go with awk which you already solved :).